# Multiple getter and setter

Tags: c#

How to create multiple handler for getter and setter, not to write same code for every field. I understand that it has some design pattern for that.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    private string _personDescription;
    private string _other;

    public TestClass() { }

    //same for lastName, personDescription, other
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = FixValue(value);
        }
    }

    private string FixValue(string value)
    {
        value = value.Trim();
        if (value == string.Empty)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had the same problem. I use Code Snippets in Visual Studio and just create a new chunk of code for each variable. [Create your own code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx). Hope that was helpful.

Comment: Yeah, there's no real clean way other than this. Usually there are some macros to make stuff like this more easy, but the result will be the same.

Comment: The only thing I can say is that if you had PostSharp or some other AOP framework you could use an aspect. I don't think there's any other way to do it in C#. PS: You should probably check if `value` is null before calling `value.Trim()`.

Comment: OT: You should really remove the setter and replace it with a method called something like "SetTrimmedFirstName()" because otherwise `string s = "test "; test.FirstName = s; Debug.Assert(test.FirstName == s);` will fail, which IMO is not nice.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way of doing this is through [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Basically, you create an aspect which defines custom functionality which is injected into your code at compile time.

An example of such a library is [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/). Take a look at the PostSharp tutorial [Property and Field Interception](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/intercept-property-field).

In your case, you need to implement the `OnSetValue` method, where you can add your custom code. Then add the attribute you created above your property.

Answer (score 0):

there is a default codesnippet called `propfull`, `propg` and `prop` (at least in visual studio 2010). but you still have to type the name and datatype. you can copy paste the snippet and modify it to call your custom method on set.

To autogenerate a property you can also **rightclick** on the **variable**, click on **refactor** then click **encapsulate field**. Enter propertyname or use default. **click ok twice** or enter.